# How do I go about creating images, which are units with traits?

Tags: javascript, html-canvas

Lets say there are 5 units, displayed as images on an html5-canvas.
Each image (unit) has a different size. For the game I need to know the size of that unit, and also it's middle point.

How and where do I save this data?
If I load the image, do I save that image data in a, f.e., an array of objects, where each object has that image attributes?

What do I do if that unit dies, do I delete that object from the array? And do I just create a object when I create a new unit again?

What structure can I use here? An array of objects doesn't seem very efficient to me (I don't even know if it works, not very experienced).

I had something like this in mind:

```
let unit_imgs = [
    {
        width,
        height,
        midpoint,
    },
    {
        width,
        height,
        midpoint,
    },
    { ... },
];
```

Any other, better, ways to do this?

Comment: Is every unit unique or can't you have just an object that holds all values of your unit that dont change?

Comment: Your way sounds like it would work. Do you experience any problems when doing it that way? For more on what Zibelas suggests, check out the [Flyweight](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/flyweight.html) and [Type Object](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/type-object.html) patterns.

Answer (score 0):

> Any other, better, ways to do this?

Separate logic and presentation: make an array of units to process their logic and a dictionary of images so that units could reference them.

Whenever you need to update canvas just iterate over your units, for every single one find an image it refers to and draw it.